# Why is every coset in G a subset of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. $Ha$ is a right coset of $H$ in $G$. According to the Dover *Book of Abstract Algebra* p. 127, "Every coset in $G$ is a subset of $G$." I understand that since $H$ is a subgroup, it is closed with respect to multiplication. But nothing guarantees that $G$ is closed, right? So if $a$ is in $G$ but not in $H$, isn't it possible that $ha$ (where $h \in H$) can give a value that is outside $G$?

Comment: $G$ is a group. So it is closed under multiplication. That's part of the definition of what makes $(G,\cdot)$ a group (where $\cdot$ is the group's multiplication operator). For every $g,h\in G$, $g\cdot h\in G$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Really? My book says that a **group** means (1) $*$ is associative, (2) there is a $e$, and (3) every $a$ in $G$ has an inverse. A **subgroup** is a nonempty subset of a group that is closed with respect to multiplication and inverses. Is there a proof that every group is closed? There are groups that are not subgroups, right?

Comment: Your book _should_ say that a group $G$ is a set equipped with a binary operation * that meets those three conditions you mention. But being a binary operation in the first place is what tells you that multiplication is closed.

Comment: Oh, you are right! p.19: "An operation $*$ on $A$ is a rule which assigns to each ordered pair $(a, b)$ of elements of $A$ exactly one element $a * b$ **in $A$**." So all operations are closed, but in addition a subgroup's operations are more tightly closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, Every group is closed under multiplication. This is a part of the definition.
Many books states only three conditions for groups namely, associativity, existence of identity element and inverses. They don't mention closure of operation under consideration.

But it's understood implicitly that the operation is closed as if $*$ is a binary operation on $G$ then it's a function from $G\times G\rightarrow G$. Hence it's closed by definition of what it mean to be a binary operation.

But some books prefer to state closure explicitly to avoid such mis-understanding like that.

To sum up, Every group must be closed under multiplication. This is essintial to be a group. 
Remember that a group is a generalization of reals, integers and so on. So, it would be good idea to compare such notions and apply them to such well-known examples, of course, commutivity is not a good property to compare!